# Is there a way to let Enigmail automatically use the passphrase to unlock my key that's stored in keypass?

Tags: thunderbird, keepass, enigmail

I use Enigmail in Thunderbird to send encrypted messages and sign messages with my own key. From an user-experience standpoint I would like to spend less time entering my passphrase to unlock the key.
I have the passphrase stored in my keypass database. Is there a way to load it automatically from the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are looking for the "Global auto-type" option? By default you can call it with `CTRL+ALT+A` (see "Options > Integration" tab):

1. open Thunderbird as usual (and open the window asking for passphrase).
2. define the autotype for your entry in Keepass:

   - edit the entry then go to Auto-type tab and click the "Add" button.
   - select the Thunderbid window in the "Target window" dropdown.
   - (adjust the "sequence" if needed).
3. Now go back to Thunderbird and try `CTRL+ALT+A` to autofill the password.

It's also good to know there are other settings you may want to adjust to trigger the Auto-Type.
(see general `option > Advanced tab > Auto-type`).

--
options > integration (define the main shortcuts): 
[image]

`Edit entry > Auto-type tab`:
[image]

define the target windows and the sequence: 
[image]